# RadioButton and an InputField, side by site, using Bootstrap 3 Form

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I put, side by site, a RadioButton and a TextInput field on my Bootstrap 3 Form?

I want to achieve this:

```
(o) A fixed value
( ) A value between [ ] and [ ]
```

(being parenthesis the RadioButton and brackets, the text box).

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour]( https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="radio" id="test">A fixed value
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="display:inline">
    <input type="radio" id="test2">A value between <input type="text" id="text1" /> and <input type="text" id="text2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Can you please mark as the correct answer then.